# Query Structure: SELECT FROM places WHERE Type = 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Okay so i am trying to display all entries in one of my database tables where the field 'Type' has a value of 1 but i keep getting an error. I'm not sure how to structure my query.

```
<?php
include 'page-start.php';
?>
<?php
$myQuery  = "SELECT places.*, Type.TypeName ";
$myQuery .= "FROM places ";
$myQuery .= "WHERE Type = '1' ";
$myQuery .= "INNER JOIN Type ON places.Type = Type.TypeID";

$result = $con->query($myQuery);
if (!$result) die('Query error: ' . mysqli_error($result));
?>



 <?php

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {

    echo ' <div class="one-third column" id="education">';
    echo '<h3 class="place-head"><a href="educationdetails.php?ID=' . $row['PlaceID'] . '">' . $row['PlaceName'] . '</a></h3>';
    echo    ' <div class="a-image">';
    echo        '<img src="'. $row['ImageURL'] . '"/>';
    echo    ' </div>';
    echo        ' <div class="a-info">';


    echo        ' </div>';
    echo    '</div>';   
            }

    ?>
```

After playing around i managed to get it working by executing the query on its own underneath the first query like this:

```
<?php
$myQuery  = "SELECT places.*, Type.TypeName ";
$myQuery .= "FROM places ";
$myQuery .= "INNER JOIN Type ON places.TypeID = Type.TypeID";

$result = $con->query($myQuery);
if (!$result) die('Query error: ' . mysqli_error($result));
?>
<?php
$myQuery = "SELECT * FROM `places` WHERE `TypeID` = '1'";
$result = $con->query($myQuery);
if (!$result) die('Query error: ' . mysqli_error($result));
?>
```

I don't know if this was the correct way of getting round my problem but it works. Thanks for the help anyway guys.

Comment: use backticks on your tables instead of columns since they share the exact same name

Comment: sorry : Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in ... line 16
Query error:

Comment: `>.>`.....where is your mysqli connection....

Comment: inside the page-start.php file, it works when i take out the "$myQuery .= "WHERE Type = '1' ";" it displays all the entries in the table

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have an SQL syntax error?

```
$myQuery  = "SELECT places.*, Type.TypeName ";
$myQuery .= "FROM places ";
$myQuery .= "WHERE Type = '1' ";
$myQuery .= "INNER JOIN Type ON places.Type = Type.TypeID";
```

The inner join should precede your predicate ("WHERE Type = '1'"):

```
$myQuery  = "SELECT places.*, Type.TypeName ";
$myQuery .= "FROM places ";
$myQuery .= "INNER JOIN Type ON places.Type = Type.TypeID";
$myQuery .= "WHERE Type = '1' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass `$result` to mysqli_error, that's not what it wants, it wants your `$con` variable passed in as the parameter.

Also, since you're using the mysqli object, just call `$con->error` to print the error message.

And since you're returning a mysqli_result objects, you should probably just use

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) )
```

as your while loop command.

Comment: i just tried that now i'm getting the error: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in

Comment: it works without the line $myQuery .= "WHERE Type = '1' "; so it there be something wrong with how i have written the query